# Recyclerview shows only one array

Tags: android, api, retrofit

I am trying to get two comments of specific post but RecyclerView shows only one comment.

This is my Api call test on Postman.

[image: Retrofit]

But when i Use this call on my app it shows only one Comment

Here is following Code

TwoCommentAdapter :

```
class TwoCommentsAdapter (var twocommentsList : ArrayList<Comments>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<TwoCommentsAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        val itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.two_comment, parent,false)
        return ViewHolder(itemView)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return twocommentsList.count()
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.comment?.setText(twocommentsList.get(position).comment)
        holder.username?.setText(twocommentsList.get(position).username)
    }

    class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        var comment : TextView? = null
        var username : TextView? = null
        init {
            this.comment = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_txt)
            this.username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.comment_user_txt)
        }
    }
}
```

Poko :

```
class Comments(val comment_id : Int, val username : String, val comment: String)
```

API Call :

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/api/getTwoComment")
fun getTwoComments(@Field("post_id") post_id: Int): Call<ArrayList<Comments>>
```

Retrofit Call in Activity :

```
getMainApp().swiftAPI.getTwoComments(post_id).enqueue(object : Callback<ArrayList<Comments>>{
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<ArrayList<Comments>>?, t: Throwable?) {
                Toast.makeText(this@ViewSinglePostActivity, t?.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
            }

            override fun onResponse(call: Call<ArrayList<Comments>>?, response: Response<ArrayList<Comments>>?) {
                if (response?.isSuccessful!!){

                    val adapter = TwoCommentsAdapter(response.body()!!)
                    two_comments_rcv.adapter = adapter
                }
            }

        })
```

Thanks in Advance. If you want anything ill provide

Comment: Have you tried logging `twocommentsList.count()` in `getItemCount()`? What does it log?

Comment: its same i use normally count and it works properly it shows 2 perfectly

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52493647/6401241 this may help's you

Comment: its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
 override fun getItemCount(): Int {
     return twocommentsList.count()
 }
```

Use this

```
 override fun getItemCount(): Int {
     return twocommentsList.size
 }
```

Some other common issue is setting wrong hight for item layout that you can see your view Scrolling or not, for fix that check [this](http://%20stackoverflow.com/a/52493647/6401241)

Comment: expression 'size of type 'Int' cannot be invoked as function

Comment: Its working properly now it was fault with my xml file i have given height = match_parent so it was taking my full view of screen